# OracleDependency not firing event

Tags: c#, oracle, dependencies

I have an Oracle Connection to a ORACLE 10.2 database and want to listen for changes to a table. The user of the connection was granted the privilege "CHANGE NOTIFICATION".

Listening is initialized with the following method:

```
private OracleDependency SubscribeToTable(string tableName)
{
  string sql = "select * from " + tableName;
  var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, this.connection) { AddRowid = true };
  var dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);
  cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
  dep.OnChange += this.dep_OnChange;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  return dep;
}
```

When i insert a row into the observed table and commit, the event dep_OnChange is never fired. What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE:

After checking the troubleshooting list and found everything to be OK, i connected as DBA to Oracle and checked the ip adresses that should be notified when a change occurs (SELECT * FROM user_change_notification_regs). For some reason the ip addresses pointed to a VMWare virtual network adapter, although the notification request was initiated from the physical machine and not a VM. After disabling that virtual network adapter, everything works like it should.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with a python program.  It worked for a while and then stopped working.  I will update with an answer if I find any clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run through the trouble shooting in the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/changenotification/ChangeNotification.htm)?

Comment: Documentation link is now invalid.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can use oracletabledependency component. You can find it at
Tabledependency.codeplex.com

Once instantiated you will receive events fot every table record modified.